# Need To Add Windows Authentication To A Basic HTML/JavaScript Site

Tags: javascript, iis, active-directory

I have a basic HTML/JavaScript site which needs to use Active Directory authentication. I need for the JavaScript to have access to the User ID of the authenticated user. This site allows users to upload images to a database and we need to store the user ID who uploaded them.

The site is running on IIS. Currently I am using IIS to handle the authentication but since my code is all client side I have no way to get the User ID of the logged in user.

What options are available that I can added to my HTML/JavaScript site to handle authentication so the JavaScript will have access to the User ID after a successfully authentication?

Will also need to limit which Active Directory group is to be allowed to authenticate in to the site.

Comment: *I am using IIS to handle the authentication but since my code is all client side I have no way to get the User ID of the logged in user* that sounds contradictory - how is IIS handling authentication if all your code is client side?

Comment: In IIS I have windows authentication turned on for this site. IIS authenticates the user before allowing the user to access the site. Once IIS authenticates the user they can then access the site. Site itself is just HTML and JavaScript with no authentication methods built in to the site code.

Comment: Surely the user can not access the database in the first place without some form of authentication being passed to it?  Doesn't your backend process already handle that?

Comment: Site calls an internal API which allows for images to be uploaded. At this time the internal API is open inside the network for this purpose. Don't want to have people authenticate to both the site and then again to the API. 
Ideally would like for the site to handle authentication. Once that is working could pass the valid user Id to the API when the site does its API call.

Comment: Looking into using XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials to get the logged in user of the browser to send to the API for authentication when the endpoint is called.

Comment: JavaScript will not be able to determine your Windows user name.
you could try to use the var username = '<%HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to close my question with the solution I ended up implementing.
Added authentication to a few of my API endpoints. Created a new endpoint which returned the userID who accessed the endpoint. The site hits this endpoint after the user logs in to the site and returns the userID so that is available for both display in the site to query to get more information such as the person's display name.

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal - I marked my answer as the accept solution. Thank you for the reminder.